# Как использовать uLogin вместе с checkbox "чужой компьютер?"?

Tags: php, checkbox, ulogin

С помощью https://ulogin.ru можно позволить пользователю логиниться используя аккаунт на другом сайте. Для этого я добавил соответствующий скрипт к форме логина:

```html
<form action="{$REQUEST_URI}" method="POST">
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="login" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                Залогиниться через социальную сеть:</td>
                <td colspan="2"><script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
                <div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=small;fields=first_name,last_name,email;providers=vkontakte,facebook,livejournal,odnoklassniki,mailru;hidden=other;redirect_uri=?"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
<...логин через стандартный ввод логин-пароль>
   <td nowrap align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;Чужой компьютер?</td>
   <td width="50%"><input type="checkbox" name="dontSavePassw" id="dontSavePassw"></td>

   <td align="right" width="50%"><input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Войти" class="btn"></td>
  </tr>
<...>
 </table>
</form>
```

Но естественно теперь по клику на uLogin кнопку, параметр dontSavePass не передается php скрипту. Как можно исправить эту ситуацию?